# how to make language file with poedit

Tags: wordpress, translate, poedit

I'm looking to make first language pack of my theme (make not translate!) and the codes that I used in my theme is like this:

```
<?php echo _e('By', 'movies'); ?>
```

So my code variable for translate is: movies
and when I try to make the first translate .po file, will be make but will not load any item and says:

> Source codes are not available.
>   The source codes that I used are: __ and _e

Source path is like this:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\tester\wp-content\themes\2015
>   movies\language

Which part of my job has problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys I found the answer! My mistake was in source path part I suppose to write it like this:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\tester\wp-content\themes\2015 movies\

not until translation files folder.

Comment: Please don’t use absolute paths there, use paths relative to the location of the PO file (e.g. “..” or “.” etc.)